# How to solve multipart/form-data request in unirest java?

Tags: java, multipartform-data, unirest

I am trying to create attachment in [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/) through Unirest java and OpenProject API. I am getting an warning

```
Jun 05, 2019 10:35:30 AM
org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: Expires=Wed, 12 Jun 2019 04:58:08 GMT; Path=/". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 04:58:08 GMT
jsonResponse : 400
```

For this code,

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post(url).basicAuth("key","password")
         .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
         .header("accept", "application/json")
         .field("file", new File("abc.txt"))
         .asJson();
System.out.println("jsonResponse : "+jsonResponse.getStatus());
Unirest.shutdown();
```

In API it is provided that the request must be as follows:

```
Headers
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

```
Body of request
--boundary-delimiter
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "fileName": "cute-cat.png",
  "description": {
    "raw": "A cute kitty, cuddling with its friends!"
  }
}

--boundary-delimiter
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="attachment"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG file data
--boundary-delimiter--
```

The required output is:

***Response code:200***

```
(Response)Header
Content-Type: application/hal+json
(Response)Body
{
    "_type": "Attachment",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/v3/attachments/1"
        },
        "container" {
            "href": "/api/v3/work_packages/1"
        },
        "author": {
            "href": "/api/v3/users/1"
        },
        "staticDownloadLocation": {
            "href": "/api/v3/attachments/1/download"
        }
        "downloadLocation": {
            "href": "/some/remote/aws/url/image.png"
        }
    },
    "id": 1,
    "fileName": "cat.png",
    "filesize": 24,
    "description": {
        "format": "plain",
        "raw": "A picture of a cute cat",
        "html": "<p>A picture of a cute cat</p>"
    },
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "digest": {
        "algorithm": "md5",
        "64c26a8403cd796ea4cf913cda2ee4a9":
    },
    "createdAt": "2014-05-21T08:51:20Z"
}
```

(This is my first question, so tell me if I do mistake in formatting question)

Thank You!!

Comment: Have you even took one glance at the error "WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: Expires=Wed, 12 Jun 2019 04:58:08 GMT; Path=/". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 04:58:08 GMT"? It is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: @Smutje Yes, Sir I have searched [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1077) and also at some other places but not getting clear idea about it. Previously I had tried with HttpClient in which I was getting 401-unauthorized status code even after adding Basic-Authorization header in it while creating a multipart/form-data request for creating an attachment in OpenProject ticketing tool. I request you to provide me the guidelines. Thank You.